# How do I discover an IPhone app on a Mac and profile the memory on it?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-profiling

**How do I discover an IPhone app on a Mac and profile the memory on it?**

I have an app on my IPhone that I would like to profile memory on.

My IPhone is tethered to a Mac. However, I am unable to discover the app using:

**XCode -> Instruments -> Choose Target**

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the app installed? Which kind of provisioning profile does it have? What is the output of `codesign -d --entitlements :- path/to/MyApp.app/MyApp`?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm new to IOS development. I'm new to using a Mac. The app is an internal business application that has some enterprise provisioning on it. The app was built using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Basically, an app needs to be installed with a developer-profile to be debuggable and to appear in Instruments. It seems that you have installed the app with a distribution-profile, so debugging is disabled. But it is hard for me to determine if this is the case, based on the details you have provided.

Comment: I am able to deploy the app from Visual Studio to the IPhone using Xamarin tools. Would that signify a developer-profile?

Comment: Change you provisioning from distribution to development and then install and then try.